# How to get Graphics.drawString to draw from bottom of bounds?

Tags: java, graphics2d

Hey :) So I was able to figure out most of the issue so far. I 'm trying to draw a button by resizing a simple button background image to fit the size of the text. Everything works well except for the actual drawing of the string. The **y** value that I give the Graphics object designates the baseline, however I would like to draw the the string above the y. So that this [image: cutoff string] doesn't happen. I gave the graphics object the y of the bottom of the **"P"** and would instead like to give it the value of the bottom of the **"y"**. Is there a way to do that by reading the String's bounds or something, or is there a way to get the Graphics object to use the passed **y** value as the definite bottom of the String?

Thanks, StrongJoshua

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can change the position at which graphics renders text, but you could give the Graphics object a higher starting position. From the fact that you managed to find the bounding box, I assume you are familiar with `LineMetrics`. You can use `LineMetrics.getDescent()` to find how much you need to adjust.

Comment: I've only yet used FontMetrics, but I'll give that a shot, thanks :)

Comment: It worked! All I need to do now is fiddle with some numbers! Thanks :)